# What is jest's equivalent of `mocha -g` (grep option)?

Tags: javascript, jestjs

Per the [Mocha documentation](https://mochajs.org/), I can run a group of tests with a particular pattern in their `describe/suite` or `it/test` block using `mocha -g`. For example `mocha -g 'filtering usernames'` only the tests with `filtering usernames` in their names.

```
Test Filters
  --fgrep, -f   Only run tests containing this string                   [string]
  --grep, -g    Only run tests matching this string or regexp           [string]
  --invert, -i  Inverts --grep and --fgrep matches                     [boolean]
```

I am now working on projects using [`jest`](https://jestjs.io/).

**How can I run tests whose name matches a pattern in Jest?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking through the Jest docs I've found the answer to this one myself - keeping the question up as the answer may be useful for others:

From https://jestjs.io/docs/en/cli

> Run tests that match this spec name (match against the name in describe or test, basically).

`jest -t name-of-spec`

Comment: And how would one run everything except what matches the "name-of-spec" (like mocha's --invert)?

Comment: @Waterlink That's an excellent question! You should write it as a proper Stackoverflow question rather than just a comment.